# xslt recursive template on parent-child data

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, recursion

I'm trying to wrap my mind around xslt.
A number of questions here on stackoverflow help (
[XSLT templates and recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835567/xslt-templates-and-recursion)
and
[XSLT for-each loop, filter based on variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709024/xslt-for-each-loop-filter-based-on-variable)
) but I'm still kinda puzzled.
I guess I'm "thinking of template as functions"
 ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506348/how-do-i-know-my-xsl-is-efficient-and-beautiful )

Anyway...my data is

```
<Entities>
    <Entity ID="8" SortValue="0" Name="test" ParentID="0" />
    <Entity ID="14" SortValue="2" Name="test2" ParentID="8" />
    <Entity ID="16" SortValue="1" Name="test3" ParentID="8" />
    <Entity ID="17" SortValue="3" Name="test4" ParentID="14" />
    <Entity ID="18" SortValue="3" Name="test5" ParentID="0" />
</Entities>
```

What I'd like as output is basically a "treeview"

```
<ul>
    <li id="entity8">
        test
        <ul>
            <li id="entity16">
                test3
            </li>
            <li id="entity14">
                test2
                <ul>
                    <li id="entity17">
                        test4
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="entity18">
        test5
    </li>
</ul>
```

The XSLT I have so far is wrong in that it definitely "thinks of templates as functions" and also throws a StackOverflowException (:-)) on execution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Entities">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//Entities/Entity[@ParentID=0]">
        <xsl:call-template name="recursive">
            <xsl:with-param name="parentEntityID" select="0"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="recursive">
        <xsl:param name="parentEntityID"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:variable name="counter" select="//Entities/Entity[@ParentID=$parentEntityID]"></xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test="count($counter) > 0">
            <xsl:if test="$parentEntityID > 0">
            </xsl:if>
                <li>
                    <xsl:variable name="entityID" select="@ID"></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="sortValue" select="@SortValue"></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="name" select="@Name"></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="parentID" select="@ParentID"></xsl:variable>                    

                    <a href=?ID={$entityID}&amp;ParentEntityID={$parentID}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
                    </a>

                    <xsl:call-template name="recursive">
                        <xsl:with-param name="parentEntityID" select="$entityID"></xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>

                </li>           
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know how to do this by code, no problem.
This time, though, I'm looking for a solution in xslt and for that any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Michael 'mital' Pedersen, Good question, upvoted. Please, do note that the currently accepted answer doesn't produce at all the wanted nested result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although `call-template` and named templates are a very useful feature of the language, if you find yourself preferring them to `apply-templates` it may be a sign that you are still thinking in functions rather than templates.  This is particularly true if the first thing you do in a named template is select a nodeset on which to operate.

Here is a simple version of what you are trying to do.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ul>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="Entities/Entity[@ParentID=0]" />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Entity">
        <li>
           <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
           <xsl:apply-templates select="../Entity[@ParentID=current()/@ID]" />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that there is no need for the counter, as the value of the "parent" provides the necessary context.

Also note that all `Entities` behave in the same way, regardless of where they are in the tree, they contain their `@Name` value, and apply the template to any `Entity` objects whose @ParentID matches the @ID of the current level.

Comment: yep simple recursion. Just as I was writing my answer

Comment: It looks so simple when explained, yet I have such a hard time thinking up this stuff myself.
Thanks for you help.
I have replace the "apply-template"-line with:
    <xsl:if test="../Entity[@ParentID=current()/@ID]">
    <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="../Entity[@ParentID=current()/@ID]" /></ul></xsl:if> 
which produces the output I was after.

Comment: This transformation doesn't produce nested results, as wanted in the question! @Michael'mital'Pedersen, please, take note.

Comment: I've also not included the id attributes on the li elements, nor have I ordered the results.  My point was to show a small, simple example with an explanation, rather than do all of Michael's work for him.

Comment: @PaulButcher, I believe that the nested structure is a key element of the wanted result -- without producing such nested structure an answer is mildly put "incomplete" --it also leaves doubts whether such code could be usable for a real solution.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev And I believe that teaching someone how to produce the results they desire is a key element of any answer - Simply publishing an XSLT that takes the input and produces an output (which, in your answer, was also not as desired, scattering unwanted elements all over the place) is  quite plainly incomplete.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev 
I strongly believe in "learning by doing". Hence I agress with PaulButcher's approach to leed the way, but not provide door-to-door-directions. Also I found a useful solution cf. the 2nd comment here, so I'm happy.
You're both helping. People like me take the hint. Others can scroll down and get the full example. Win-win :-)
Just agree to disagree, guys. I thank you both!

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I have just been testing a bit more on your solution (the test didn't work for me untill I added a counter: <xsl:if test="count(key('kChildren', @ID)) > 0">), and I must say it's efficient. I failed to mention that I planned to use this on HUGE amounts of data. Just now I tested your xslt on 11000 row where it performs 80(!) times better than Paul's xslt.

Comment: @Michael'mital'Pedersen, BTW, `<xsl:if test="key('kChildren', @ID)">` is equivalent to `<xsl:if test="count(key('kChildren', @ID)) > 0">`  -- if you have any problem with the former this means that your XSLT processor is buggy/non-compliant. I always test my solutions before publishing them, and actually copy and paste the result of the transformation into the answer.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Yes, I would assume that they are the same. However, only the latter works in my .NET app using System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform() with XmlReader and TextWriter.

Comment: @Michael'mital'Pedersen, That sounds like a bug. Could you, please, provide a small code example to reproduce this?

Answer (score 1):

**A solution that is *correct* and *efficient* (the currently accepted answer doesn't produce the wanted nested `ul` elements:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="Entity" use="@ParentID"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*[Entity]">
     <ul>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kChildren', '0')">
            <xsl:sort select="@SortValue" data-type="number"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
     </ul>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Entity">
   <li id="entity{@ID}">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;               ', @Name, '&#xA;')"/>
      <xsl:if test="key('kChildren', @ID)">
          <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kChildren', @ID)">
              <xsl:sort select="@SortValue" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </ul>
      </xsl:if>
   </li>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Entities>
    <Entity ID="8" SortValue="0" Name="test" ParentID="0" />
    <Entity ID="14" SortValue="2" Name="test2" ParentID="8" />
    <Entity ID="16" SortValue="1" Name="test3" ParentID="8" />
    <Entity ID="17" SortValue="3" Name="test4" ParentID="14" />
    <Entity ID="18" SortValue="3" Name="test5" ParentID="0" />
</Entities>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<ul>
   <li id="entity8">
               test
<ul>
         <li id="entity16">
               test3
</li>
         <li id="entity14">
               test2
<ul>
               <li id="entity17">
               test4
</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="entity18">
               test5
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually, when I test this with current set of data 
    <Entities>
    <Entity ID="8" SortValue="0" Name="test" ParentID="0" />
    <Entity ID="14" SortValue="1" Name="test2" ParentID="17" />
    <Entity ID="16" SortValue="2" Name="test3" ParentID="17" />
    <Entity ID="17" SortValue="3" Name="test4" ParentID="8" />
    </Entities>
the resulting markup is incorrect (?)

Comment: @Michael'mital'Pedersen, What do you mean by "incorrect"? I verified that the result is the one that you want -- maybe the indentation of the text nodes isn't nexactly the one in your published wanted result, but as we well know, in HTML in this case whitespace is displayed as a single space character.

Comment: @Michael'mital'Pedersen, OK, I was wondering why you don't use the `SortValue` attribute in your code and was going to ask if it was needed at all. Now I see that the elements in your wanted result are sorted by its values. See my updated solution.

Comment: When I use your xslt with the data from my comment above the output becomes:
<ul>
  <li id="entity8">
               test
<ul><li id="entity17">
               test4
<ul><li id="entity14">
               test2
<ul /></li><li id="entity16">
               test3
<ul /></li></ul></li></ul></li>
</ul>

Incorrectly nested and with '<ul />' tags?!
+1 for the sorting part, though :-)

Comment: @Michael'mital'Pedersen, I fixed this and updated my answer -- 11hrs. ago. Please, do have a look.