# Recursive matching of data to make a hierarchy tree

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, xslt-1.0, hierarchical-data

**My input xml looks like this:**

```
<AGROVOC xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<CONCEPT>
    <Language>EN</Language>
    <termcode>331000</termcode>
    <termspell>site</termspell>
    <NT>12861</NT>
    <NT>13893</NT>
    <NT>15988</NT>
    <NT>24183</NT>
    <NT>28623</NT>
    <NT>35171</NT>
    <NT>4781</NT>
    <NT>5973</NT>
    <NT>8872</NT>
    <NT>9000162</NT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>12861</termcode>
    <termspell>child nurseries</termspell>
    <BT>331000</BT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>13893</termcode>
    <termspell>restaurants</termspell>
    <BT>331000</BT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>15988</termcode>
    <termspell>laboratories</termspell>
    <BT>331000</BT>
    <NT>24298</NT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>24298</termcode>
    <termspell>Veterinary laboratories</termspell>
    <BT>15988</BT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>24183</termcode>
    <termspell>hospitals</termspell>
    <BT>331000</BT>
    <NT>16384</NT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>16384</termcode>
    <termspell>animal hospitals</termspell>
    <BT>24183</BT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>35171</termcode>
    <termspell>Landfills</termspell>
    <BT>331000</BT>
    <NT>35165</NT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>35165</termcode>
    <termspell>waste landfills</termspell>
    <BT>35171</BT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>4781</termcode>
    <termspell>meteorological stations</termspell>
    <BT>331000</BT>
    <NT>8342</NT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>8342</termcode>
    <termspell>Weather ships</termspell>
    <BT>4781</BT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>5973</termcode>
    <termspell>plant nurseries</termspell>
    <BT>331000</BT>
    <NT>34832</NT>
    <NT>34830</NT>
    <NT>14969</NT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>34832</termcode>
    <termspell>Fruit tree nurseries</termspell>
    <BT>5973</BT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>34830</termcode>
    <termspell>Forest nurseries</termspell>
    <BT>5973</BT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>14969</termcode>
    <termspell>Ornamental tree nurseries</termspell>
    <BT>5973</BT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>8872</termcode>
    <termspell>Apiaries</termspell>
    <BT>331000</BT>
</CONCEPT>

<CONCEPT>
    <termcode>9000162</termcode>
    <termspell>Telecentre</termspell>
    <BT>331000</BT>
</CONCEPT>
```

**The desired output should look like this:**

```
<node id="331000" label="site">
    <isComposedBy>
        <node id="12861" label="child nurseries"/>
        <node id="13893" label="restaurants"/>
        <node id="15988" label="laboratories">
            <isComposedBy>
                <node id="24298" label="Veterinary laboratories"/>
            </isComposedBy>
        </node>
        <node id="24183" label="hospitals">
            <isComposedBy>
                <node id="16384" label="animal hospitals"/>
            </isComposedBy>
        </node>
        <node id="35171" label="Landfills">
            <isComposedBy>
                <node id="35165" label="waste landfills"/>
            </isComposedBy>
        </node>
        <node id="4781" label="meteorological stations">
            <isComposedBy>
                <node id="8342" label="Weather ships"/>
            </isComposedBy>
        </node>
        <node id="5973" label="plant nurseries">
            <isComposedBy>
                <node id="34832" label="Fruit tree nurseries"/>
                <node id="34830" label="Forest nurseries"/>
                <node id="14969" label="Ornamental tree nurseries"/>
            </isComposedBy>
        </node>
        <node id="8872" label="Apiaries"/>
        <node id="9000162" label="Telecentre"/>
    </isComposedBy>
</node>
```

From the given xml above, a concept can only have 1 BT or broader term which is its parent's ID. If it doesn't contain a BT, it means that it is at the top of the hierarchy (e.g. site). A concept can have multiple NTs or children.

**My xsl looks like this:**

```
<xsl:key name="kChildren" match="CONCEPT" use="BT"/>
    <xsl:template match="CONCEPT">
    <xsl:element name="node">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="/AGROVOC/CONCEPT/termcode"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kChildren', '0')"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CONCEPT">
    <xsl:element name="node">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="termcode"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="label">
            <xsl:value-of select="termspell"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:if test="key('kChildren', termcode)">
            <isComposedBy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kChildren', termcode)"/>
            </isComposedBy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**The output looks like the desired output PLUS this:**

```
<node id="12861" label="child nurseries"/>
<node id="13893" label="restaurants"/>
<node id="15988" label="laboratories">
    <isComposedBy>
        <node id="24298" label="Veterinary laboratories"/>
    </isComposedBy>
</node>
<node id="24298" label="Veterinary laboratories"/>
<node id="24183" label="hospitals">
    <isComposedBy>
        <node id="16384" label="animal hospitals"/>
    </isComposedBy>
</node>
<node id="16384" label="animal hospitals"/>
<node id="35171" label="Landfills">
    <isComposedBy>
        <node id="35165" label="waste landfills"/>
    </isComposedBy>
</node>
<node id="35165" label="waste landfills"/>
<node id="4781" label="meteorological stations">
    <isComposedBy>
        <node id="8342" label="Weather ships"/>
    </isComposedBy>
</node>
<node id="8342" label="Weather ships"/>
<node id="5973" label="plant nurseries">
    <isComposedBy>
        <node id="34832" label="Fruit tree nurseries"/>
        <node id="34830" label="Forest nurseries"/>
        <node id="14969" label="Ornamental tree nurseries"/>
    </isComposedBy>
</node>
<node id="34832" label="Fruit tree nurseries"/>
<node id="34830" label="Forest nurseries"/>
<node id="14969" label="Ornamental tree nurseries"/>
<node id="8872" label="Apiaries"/>
<node id="9000162" label="Telecentre"/>
```

Any ideas how can I remove the extra nodes that were just repeated? BTW, I patterned my xsl from this post: [xslt recursive template on parent-child data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644680/xslt-recursive-template-on-parent-child-data). Thanks in advance.

Comment: euler, In the provided output "plant nurseries" has three children, but in the provided source XML document, "plant nurseries" doesn't have any children. Please, edit and correct.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, thank you so much, that was quick! Thumbs up for you!;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kConcByCode" match="CONCEPT" use="termcode"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/CONCEPT[not(BT)]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="CONCEPT">
  <node id="{termcode}" label="{termspell}">
   <xsl:if test="key('kConcByCode', NT)">
     <isComposedBy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kConcByCode', NT)"/>
     </isComposedBy>
   </xsl:if>
  </node>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<AGROVOC xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CONCEPT>
        <Language>EN</Language>
        <termcode>331000</termcode>
        <termspell>site</termspell>
        <NT>12861</NT>
        <NT>13893</NT>
        <NT>15988</NT>
        <NT>24183</NT>
        <NT>28623</NT>
        <NT>35171</NT>
        <NT>4781</NT>
        <NT>5973</NT>
        <NT>8872</NT>
        <NT>9000162</NT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>12861</termcode>
        <termspell>child nurseries</termspell>
        <BT>331000</BT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>13893</termcode>
        <termspell>restaurants</termspell>
        <BT>331000</BT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>15988</termcode>
        <termspell>laboratories</termspell>
        <BT>331000</BT>
        <NT>24298</NT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>24298</termcode>
        <termspell>Veterinary laboratories</termspell>
        <BT>15988</BT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>24183</termcode>
        <termspell>hospitals</termspell>
        <BT>331000</BT>
        <NT>16384</NT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>16384</termcode>
        <termspell>animal hospitals</termspell>
        <BT>24183</BT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>35171</termcode>
        <termspell>Landfills</termspell>
        <BT>331000</BT>
        <NT>35165</NT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>35165</termcode>
        <termspell>waste landfills</termspell>
        <BT>35171</BT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>4781</termcode>
        <termspell>meteorological stations</termspell>
        <BT>331000</BT>
        <NT>8342</NT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>8342</termcode>
        <termspell>Weather ships</termspell>
        <BT>4781</BT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>5973</termcode>
        <termspell>plant nurseries</termspell>
        <BT>331000</BT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>34832</termcode>
        <termspell>Fruit tree nurseries</termspell>
        <BT>5973</BT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>34830</termcode>
        <termspell>Forest nurseries</termspell>
        <BT>5973</BT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>14969</termcode>
        <termspell>Ornamental tree nurseries</termspell>
        <BT>5973</BT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>8872</termcode>
        <termspell>Apiaries</termspell>
        <BT>331000</BT>
    </CONCEPT>
    <CONCEPT>
        <termcode>9000162</termcode>
        <termspell>Telecentre</termspell>
        <BT>331000</BT>
    </CONCEPT>
</AGROVOC>
```

**produces the correct result**:

```
<node id="331000" label="site">
   <isComposedBy>
      <node id="12861" label="child nurseries"/>
      <node id="13893" label="restaurants"/>
      <node id="15988" label="laboratories">
         <isComposedBy>
            <node id="24298" label="Veterinary laboratories"/>
         </isComposedBy>
      </node>
      <node id="24183" label="hospitals">
         <isComposedBy>
            <node id="16384" label="animal hospitals"/>
         </isComposedBy>
      </node>
      <node id="35171" label="Landfills">
         <isComposedBy>
            <node id="35165" label="waste landfills"/>
         </isComposedBy>
      </node>
      <node id="4781" label="meteorological stations">
         <isComposedBy>
            <node id="8342" label="Weather ships"/>
         </isComposedBy>
      </node>
      <node id="5973" label="plant nurseries"/>
      <node id="8872" label="Apiaries"/>
      <node id="9000162" label="Telecentre"/>
   </isComposedBy>
</node>
```